# Blocking multiprocessing pool.map called in a process

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I want to call a `multiprocessing.pool.map` inside a **process**.

When initialized inside the `run()` function, it works. When initialized at instantiation, it does not.

I cannot figure the reason for this behavior ? What happens in the process ?
I am on python 3.6

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Process, Queue

def DummyPrinter(key):
    print(key)

class Consumer(Process):
    def __init__(self, task_queue):
        Process.__init__(self)
        self.task_queue = task_queue
        self.p = Pool(1)

def run(self):
    p = Pool(8)
    while True:
        next_task = self.task_queue.get()
        if next_task is None:
            break

        p.map(DummyPrinter, next_task) #  Works
        #self.p.map(DummyPrinter, next_task)   #  Does not Work
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    task_queue = Queue()
    Consumer(task_queue).start()

    task_queue.put(range(5))
    task_queue.put(None)
```

Comment: I suppose that you are using windows then?

Comment: On Ubuntu, edited

Comment: can you show the code that _doesn't_ work, not the one that works? I think I solved an issue like that. Let me find it

Comment: just uncomment #self.p.map(DummyPrinter, next_task)   #  Does not Work

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: it never returns

Answer (score 2):

`multiprocessing.Pool` cannot be shared by multiple processes because it relies on pipes and threads for its functioning.

The `__init__` method gets executed in the parent process whereas the `run` logic belongs to the child process.

I usually recommend against sub-classing the `Process` object as it's quite counter intuitive.

A logic like the following would better show the actual division of responsibilities.

```
def function(task_queue):
    """This runs in the child process."""
    p = Pool(8)
    while True:
        next_task = self.task_queue.get()
        if next_task is None:
            break

        p.map(DummyPrinter, next_task) #  Works

def main():
    """This runs in the parent process."""
    task_queue = Queue()
    process = Process(target=function, args=[task_queue])
    process.start()
```